# On a Mac OS X, Ctrl-Backspace generates ascii code 8 (backspace), which is almost invisible but very annoying

Tags: keyboard

When I press Ctrl-Backspace, Mathematica inserts what looks either like a tiny white space or sometimes is invisible. Actually, though, it is an ascii character code 8, also enterable in Mathematica as `\.08`. The presence of this character completely messes up code and is very difficult to diagnose (for example, `\.08a` is different from `a`, but they look identical).

I can't imagine the purpose of this behavior but I desperately want to get rid of it. Ideally, Ctrl-Backspace would delete the previous word, like in a sensible application. I would be completely content, though, with disabling all behavior when I press Ctrl-Backspace.

I have tried looking in KeyEventTranslations.tr but I didn't find the origin of this behavior.

Note that I am using Mac OS X 10.9.3 and Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on a MacBook 2012.

Comment: "Ideally, Ctrl-Backspace would delete the previous word, like in a sensible application." ...and like it works here on my Linux box.

Comment: Don't fight OS X, learn how to use it. The standard modifier key for operations on full words is Option, not Control like on Windows/Linux. Use Option-Delete to delete the previous word.

Comment: FYI, this remains an issue in Mathematica 10.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer, but I think it casts some light on the insidiousness of the problem jondaman21 has found.

[image: code]

Before the last input line was evaluated `\.0842` had the color of an unevaluated symbol, but after the last input line was evaluated it is visually indistinguishable from integer 42.