# `NotebookEventActions` for special keys ("F2", "F3", "pause", etc.) on Windows

Tags: notebooks, keyboard

Using `NotebookEventActions` one can make MMA evaluate a function when a key is pressed.
For example:

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[],
  NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown","x"} :> Print["You pressed \"x\"!"]}
]
```

will print a sentence every time the user presses "x" on the keyboard.

**How do I use `NotebookEventActions` to do something when the user presses one of the function keys "F2", "F3, ..., "F12", or a special key, such as "pause"?**

**If** this is not possible, then how can I make my program react to special keys with a mechanism other than `NotebookEventActions`? It is important that the change is local to one notebook, and that it can be made programmatically.

Comment: AFAIK there is no documented way to do this. There might be undocumented ways, so maybe we are lucky and someone is able to answer...

Comment: You can edit `KeyEventTranslations.tr` but it will be active across all notebooks.

Comment: @Kuba: I know, but I need it to be local to the current notebook, and I need to change it programmatically.

Comment: Find the key-code for them and pass that to `KeyDown`.

Comment: @b3m2a1: I have tried that. But `EventHandler[InputField[], {{"KeyDown", 113} :> Print["!"]}]` does not work, since Google says "F2" corresponds to 113, but FromCharacterCode[113] gives "q".

Comment: See this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139748

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData["\"Try the function keys\""],
  "Output",
  CellEventActions -> {
    {"KeyDown", "\.10"} :> Print["this should work"]
    },
  CellEditDuplicate -> False
  ]
 ]
```

I found that by using this trick

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData["\"Type here to determine key type\""],
  "Output",
  CellEventActions -> {
    "KeyDown" :>
     (
      SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, CellContents];
      NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],
       ToBoxes[
          <|
           "Name" -> CharacterName[#, "UnicodeName"],
           "Display" -> #,
           "KeyRaw" -> FullForm[#]
           |>
          ] &@CurrentValue["EventKey"]
       ]
      )
    },
  CellEditDuplicate -> False
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Hi @b3m2a1. Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it does not react to any function keys or special keys on my keyboard. May this depend on the OS? I got Windows 10, and MMA version 11.0.1.

Comment: This is for Mac. Use that second block of code to determine what your function key binds to.

Comment: @b3m2a1 does not work for F* on Win according to my test. Anyway, isn't it a duplicate of the question you've linked?

Comment: @Kuba yeah I’d agree with that. I didn’t realize the other one was about more than just backspace.

Comment: @Kuba: This is why I added the "on Windows" to the title, but I guess it is best to have everything in one place. I figured out how to do this on Windows, and posted it in the main question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167223/35390, as I cannot answer my own question anymore.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Yes, that was the point, to keep relevant answers in one place. Sorry didn't noticed you wanted to make clear it is specifically about Windows.  And yes, I've already seen it and upvoted. Will have to play with it soon.