# What is the name of the Page Down key when using EventHandler?

Tags: keyboard, eventhandler

I want to trap the PageDown event in an EventHandler. The code I've written is working fine for, say, "RightArrowKeyDown". But for the life of me I can't find the label for the Page Down key. I've tried "PageDownKeyDown" and variations using Pg and Dn but none of these seem to work. There is also no documentation on the labels of the keys other than those keys explicitly mentioned on the EventHandler help page.

Does anyone know what label to use?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Special Key Presses in a Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139704/how-to-detect-special-key-presses-in-a-notebook) - From my testing, PageDown and PageUp cannot be captured by `EventHandler` though (these keys down event trigger an unfiltered `"KeyDown"` event handler)

Comment: Thanks. I'm running on Windows so even the specifications for keys that are given for the Mac don't work, with the exception of "\r" for the Return key.
CurrentValue also only seems to respond to alphanumerics and the modifier keys.
I just don't understand the reason for such a limitation on the part of Wolfram.